# How do I have to write a Search Query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, elasticsearch, grails-2.0

I use the Grails ElasticSearch Plugin and want to use the following query:

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    },
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "age" : { "from" : 10, "to" : 20 }
        }
    },
    "should" : [
        {
            "term" : { "tag" : "wow" }
        },
        {
            "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" }
        }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 1,
    "boost" : 1.0
}
```

Using the groovy api from the Grails plugin I would write something like:

```
def res = userAgentIdentService.search() {
    "bool" {
        "must" {
            term("user" : "kimchy" )
        }
        "must_not"  {
            "range"  {
                age("from" : 10, "to" : 20 }
            }
        }
        "should" : [
            {
                term( "tag" : "wow" )
            }
            {
                term("tag" : "elasticsearch" )
            }
        ]
        "minimum_should_match" = 1
        "boost" = 1.0
    } 

}
```

My query is not working!

1. Where do I have to define minimum_should_match and how do I have to define it?
2. How do I have to write the "should" : [ ... ] square brackets notation in the grails / groovy manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a couple of json levels in your search request. I don't think you can use the query without specifying that's a query (it could be a filter as well, or even something else). Have a look at [this example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/clients/groovy-api/search/) from the groovy api reference:

```
def search = node.client.search {
    indices "test"
    types "type1"
    source {
        query {
            terms(test: ["value1", "value2"])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write the query with the search function of the plugin?

Comment: I updated my answer with the example I mentioned. sorry for the delay